# Serve Angular2 app not on root

Tags: angular

I have a Rails 5 API with an Angular 2 front end.

How can I configure my Angular2 app not to run on "/", but instead have it load on "/app"?

BaseURL is deprecated, and base href has no effect. I've read many many pages of instructions but most are outdated, or simply don't work.

Comment: Is your Rails API also doing routing?

Comment: @gelliott181 Yes. I have an API scope defined: "scope '/api' do...." and all my resources are within that scope. The Angular app accesses the API under this path.

Comment: The angular router won't direct requests properly if your first router  dumps all requests to `/app` as 404s.

Comment: OK I'll keep that in mind but my router isn't dumping all requests to "/app". I have a sign-up page ("/sign-up"), and sign-in page ("/sign-in") and faq page ("/faq") that all work through the rails router. It's only "/" that redirects to "/app" and I can't stop it. I think I will post a new question asking about how to hide an angular app behind a static page.

Comment: My mistake using 'dumping'. I meant dropped, sent to /dev/null, blackholed, etc. The server should have been responding 404 to any requests that didn't have a route.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I'm assuming requests go through a server before hitting your Angular 2 app.

```
request -> server -> route -> api
request -> server -> route -> app -> route
```

Based on this, you'll need the server to route `/app` to your angular app, and then set your base href to `/app`.

This is based on what I did to get my HapiJS back end to properly serve my Angular 2 routes.

Comment: OK I figured one thing out. I had a proxy config problem. Now I can get the app to run on "/app" but what is still happening is if you land on "/", the angular app loads, and redirects you to "/app". So I guess this is more of a rails question. How do I get rails to handle "/" on its own instead of passing the request on to the Angular app?

Comment: This one is outside my knowledge as I don't have any Rails experience. I'd assume you just need to configure `/` to be explicitly handle in the Rails server instead of getting sent to `/app`.